# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01747

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sqlexception

When i am running the following SQL query i am getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

String strQuery = "UPDATE themed_night SET theme_night_name = ?, theme_night_date = TO_DATE(?, 'dd-MM-yy'), theme_night_description = ?, WHERE theme_id = ?";
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);//prepare the SQL Query
        stmt.setString(1, title);
        stmt.setString(2, output);
        stmt.setString(3, details);
        stmt.setString(4, themeID);
```

Is my SQL query syntax correct? I have double checked the columns and i have typed the correct names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra comma in your statement. The correct statement should be

```
String strQuery = "UPDATE themed_night SET theme_night_name = ?, theme_night_date = TO_DATE(?, 'dd-MM-yy'), theme_night_description = ? WHERE theme_id = ?";
```

Also, you might need to enclose some values with single quotes (though I'm not sure about that)

Comment: woops, didnt see that. Its been a long day -_-

Comment: No worries! Happens to all of us

Comment: i did the same mistake -_-. +1 though